# How to delete a domain from a Domain Controller, but keep the subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, migration

If I have a domain : **corporate.com**

With 3 subdomains :

- dev.corporate.com
- voice.corporate.com
- vpn.corporate.com

How can I delete the top domain, but keep the 3 child zones?

Specifically for Windows DNS, this would look something like this :
[image]

I suspect there is no easy way to do this, which means I manually have to edit the entire zone file to end up with 3 separate zone files for the child zones. But I'm hoping I'm wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot delete corporate.com and keep dev,voice and vpn, without ending up with three separate zones.  What is the goal?  Are you trying to resolve records in the root corporate.com with another DNS server?

Comment: Yes we're trying to move corporate.com to a different DNS server. But keep the child domains as they are in the current server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible until you make 3 separate zones for 3 subdomains. Are you trying to move your main domain onto another server? If you want to do this there is no other option except to develop 3 separate zone.

Comment: This is not a bad idea actually. Separate the 3 zones first on the same server. Then migrate off the parent.

Yes the client wanted to move the main domain to another server, but still keep the 3 child domains on the original server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this without some heavy modification of the data (programmatically modifying the zone data file to remove the parent zone, and then reloading the zone from the new file).

Indeed it is far simpler to migrate things in the opposite order

- Migrate subzones first (using zone transfer)
- Then migrate the parent zone if needed